# Find the solution of differential equation $(2y+xy^3)dx +(x+x^2y^2)dy =0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of differential equation $(2y+xy^3)dx +(x+x^2y^2)dy =0$

Please suggest not getting any idea how to proceed this type of equation as it is neither homogeneous nor linear equation. Please suggest will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: perhaps it is of this type, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation Exact differential equation

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBW20zY9Sm0

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $3x$ we have
$$\eqalign{(6xy+3x^2y^3)+(3x^2+3x^3y^2)\frac{dy}{dx}=0\quad
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad \frac{d}{dx}(3x^2y+x^3y^3)=0\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad 3x^2y+x^3y^3=C\ .\cr}$$
How would you know to multiply by $3x$? - see the YouTube video linked above.

Comment: I am not getting how to get 3x after watching your video sorry for that... can you explain with example ... will be of great help...

Answer (score 0):

The equation has two groups of two terms with common degrees in $x$ and $y$,
$$
0=[2y\,dx+x\,dy] + [xy^3\,dx+x^2y^2\,dy]
$$
Both can be written as products of a monomial and the derivative of a monomial
$$
=x^{-1}\,d(x^2y)+xy^2\,d(xy)=x^{-1}[d(x^2y)+(xy)^2\,d(xy)]
$$
The last term is fully integrable after multiplication with $x$, so that $x$ (or any multiple of it) is an integrating factor and the solutions are the level curves
$$
C=x^2y+\frac13(xy)^3.
$$